# d.rast.edit error when attempting to edit a raster

Tags: raster, grass-gis

I always get an error when I try to edit cell values in a raster with the GrassGIS command „d.rast.edit“.
The error under Windows XP/GrassGIS 6.4.3 says:

```
Exception in thread Thread-29:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\threading.py", line
552, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "D:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3RC1\etc\wxpython\co
re\gcmd.py", line 538, in run
    os.pathsep + env['PATH']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3RC1\etc\wxpython\gu
i_core\forms.py", line 657, in OnRun

gcmd.Command(cmd)
  File "D:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3RC1\etc\wxpython\co
re\gcmd.py", line 389, in __init__

_("Error: ") + self.__GetError()))
core.gcmd
.
GException
Exception in thread Thread-30:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\threading.py", line
552, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "D:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3RC1\etc\wxpython\co
re\gcmd.py", line 538, in run
    os.pathsep + env['PATH']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3RC1\etc\wxpython\gu
i_core\forms.py", line 657, in OnRun

gcmd.Command(cmd)
  File "D:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3RC1\etc\wxpython\co
re\gcmd.py", line 389, in __init__

_("Error: ") + self.__GetError()))
core.gcmd
.
GException
```

… and under openSUSE 11 SP2/ Grass GIS 6.4.2:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/grass-6.4.2/etc/wxpython/gui_modules/menu
form.py", line 662, in OnRun

gcmd.Command(cmd)
  File
"/usr/local/grass-6.4.2/etc/wxpython/gui_modules/gcmd.py",
line 350, in __init__

_("Error: ") + self.__GetError()))
gui_modules.gcmd
.
GException
:
Execution failed: 'd.rast.edit --overwrite --verbose
input=DEM_m_float_polypoi@PERMANENT output=123456'
Details:
Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/grass-6.4.2/etc/wxpython/gui_modules/menu
form.py", line 662, in OnRun

gcmd.Command(cmd)
  File
"/usr/local/grass-6.4.2/etc/wxpython/gui_modules/gcmd.py",
line 350, in __init__

_("Error: ") + self.__GetError()))
gui_modules.gcmd
.
GException
:
Execution failed: 'd.rast.edit --overwrite --verbose
input=DEM_m_float_polypoi@PERMANENT output=123456'
Details:
Error:
```

Does anyone have an idea about the reason why I'm getting this error and/or how to avoid it ?

Answer (score 1):

I see that you used grass-6.4.3RC1, good (so no need to suggest to you to try it first).

Please report the bug here: http://trac.osgeo.org/grass/