# d.rast.edit not yet implemented in the WxGUI

Tags: raster, grass-gis, editing, grass-7.0

Am using GRASS to modify a raster and tried using d.rast.edit but am getting the following error when using it in the WxGUI

Command 'd.rast.edit' not yet implemented in the WxGUI. Try adding it as a command layer instead

But am not sure how to add it as a command layer. I looked for information here
[d.rast.edit error when attempting to edit a raster](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43971/d-rast-edit-error-when-attempting-to-edit-a-raster)

but am not sure if it is the same issue. I also looked for information in the manual
https://grass.osgeo.org/grass76/manuals/d.rast.edit.html

But whenever i type d.rast.edit in the console in get the same error.

Does anyone knows how to address this? or an alternative methodology to modify a raster in GRASS?

Am using GRASS 7.4.2 in Windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open it with

> d.rast.edit --ui

A related ticket is now open: https://trac.osgeo.org/grass/ticket/3711 in order to get rid of the error message you received.